# Command to disable windows 7 sleep

Tags: windows-7, electrical-power

Normal way to disable Win7 sleep is to go to Power Management and find current power profile, then select never for sleep option. However, I was wondering if there's any way to do this in command line or any other faster way? Please advise, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`powercfg` is the command line tool.

Use

```
powercfg -?
```

to see help.

(For regular use, you'll want to wrap it in a PowerShell or Cmd script.)

Comment: powercfg -change -standby-timeout-ac 0, from http://superuser.com/questions/90415/prevent-sleep-in-scripts

Answer (score 1):

Nice Shortcuts are:

- powercfg -ALIASES # Lists named aliases for available profiles.
- powercfg -S SCHEME_MIN #Activates the (High-Performance) Scheme with the alias SCHEME_MIN
- powercfg -S SCHEME_MAX #Activates the (Max-Energie-Saving) Scheme with the alias SCHEME_MAX
- powercfg -S SCHEME_BALANCED # ... Balanced Energie Scheme

cheers

Kai